# LDAP: How to get all Groups in Active Directory?

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

Is there a way to get the names of all groups in Active Directory using java?

Answer (score 10):

Use Java JNDI, and do a search for (objectclass=group) and request the cn attribute. This will get all the groups name.

Code example:

```
import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.Attributes;
import javax.naming.directory.DirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchControls;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchResult;

public class Test {

    public static String ldapUri = "ldap://localhost";
    public static String usersContainer = "cn=users,dc=example,dc=com";

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.out.println("Usage: test userName password");
            return;
        }
        String username = args[0];
        String password = args[1];

        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapUri);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
        try {
            DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
            SearchControls ctls = new SearchControls();
            String[] attrIDs = { "cn" };
            ctls.setReturningAttributes(attrIDs);
            ctls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.ONELEVEL_SCOPE);

            NamingEnumeration answer = ctx.search(usersContainer, "(objectclass=group)", ctls);
            while (answer.hasMore()) {
                SearchResult rslt = (SearchResult) answer.next();
                Attributes attrs = rslt.getAttributes();
                System.out.println(attrs.get("cn"));
            }

            ctx.close();

        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I try using this, I get following error: "javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 00000000: LdapErr: DSID-0C090627, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, vece"     Any idea?

Comment: Looks like you you have not authenticated correctly. Are you connecting to the correct ldap server? Is your user fdn is correct (like cn=Administrator,cn=users,dc=example,dc=com) and is your password correct?

Comment: Yes, my pw was wrong (stupid me). Anyway, now I get following: "javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090334, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 525, vece"

Comment: I think I succeeded a bit, but this is what i get now: "javax.naming.PartialResultException: [LDAP: error code 10 - 0000202B: RefErr: DSID-031006E0, data 0, 1 access points
        ref 1: 'example.com'
]; remaining name 'cn=testuser,dc=example,dc=com'" testuser is the name of user that I use. Is there something wrong with my userContainer? public static String usersContainer = "cn=testuser,dc=example,dc=com"; ???
"

Comment: change the userContainer to "dc=example,dc=com". We are using userContainer as the basedn for the search. I just used an example "cn=users,dc=example,dc=com". Change it based on your directory structure.

Comment: How filter by user ?

Comment: The problem is the number of requests to the LDAP server will be as the number of groups existing! is there a way to get all groups in one request?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this library. It's easy to use and powerfull

http://code.google.com/p/jedi-obi/

Comment: @ceving see this link http://code.google.com/p/jedi-obi/wiki/HomeUkVersion
But just this, I see that all the Java DOC is in English

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Answer (score 0):

I used Kalyan's example to query for user groups, but found that although the query worked, it did not returned all user groups. After some digging, I became aware of the AD Global Catalogue and based [this example](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1157471?tstart=0), I was able to modify Kalyan's answer to return all user groups from the global catalogue.

The required changes were:

1. Added global port `3268` to the ldapUri
2. Set the first parameter to `Context.search` to `""`.

   ```
   public static void main(String args[]) {
       String ldapUri = "ldap://ad.domain.com";

       if (args.length != 2) {
           System.out.println("Usage: test userName password");
           return;
       }
       String username = args[0];
       String password = args[1];

       Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
       env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
               "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
       env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapUri + ":3268");
       env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username);
       env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
       try {
           DirContext context = new InitialDirContext(env);
           SearchControls searchControls = new SearchControls();
           String[] attrIDs = {"cn"};
           searchControls.setReturningAttributes(attrIDs);
           searchControls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

           NamingEnumeration answer = context.search("", "(objectclass=group)", searchControls);
           while (answer.hasMore()) {
               SearchResult rslt = (SearchResult) answer.next();
               Attributes attrs = rslt.getAttributes();
               System.out.println(attrs.get("cn"));
           }

           context.close();


       } catch (NamingException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

   }
   ```